# jQuery Scroll Top Scrolling Past Desired Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrolltop

im trying to use the scrollTop function to scroll to a specific div based on a requirement, however, on desktop (google chrome) the scroll often goes maybe 100px past the div, and on mobile (safari & chrome) the webpage scrolls all the way to the bottom. what am i doing wrong?

Also, on mobile .slideDown() does not open the div, however the icon does change from plus to minus

```
    // physiotherapy department
    if (get_department == 'physiotherapy'){
        jQuery('.accordion').find(`#physiotherapists .link-content`).slideDown();
        jQuery('.accordion').find(`#physiotherapists .link`).addClass('open');
        jQuery('.accordion').find(`#physiotherapists .link a i`).removeClass('fa-plus');
        jQuery('.accordion').find(`#physiotherapists .link a i`).addClass('fa-minus');
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery("#physiotherapists").offset().top
    }, 800);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mind posting the html and css so we fiddle it?